# How to delete-process with similar name (one at a time) from newest to oldest

Tags: emacs, elisp, dired

I have a situation where I may have several processes running simultaneously with the following names:

```
preview
preview<1>
preview<2>
preview<3>
preview<4>
```

I am looking for some assistance, please, to create a function that will delete the newest process (i.e., the one with the highest number) each time the function is activated -- until the processes with numbers no longer exist, and then delete the final process (preview) without a number.

In other words, calling the function once would delete `preview<4>` -- calling the function again would delete `preview<3>`, and so on until all of them are gone.

I have a function that previews the file contents from dired mode on an OSX machine using:

EDIT:   Replaced `(car (dired-get-marked-files))` with `(dired-get-file-for-visit)`, which permits acting upon the file underneath the cursor even though others have been marked already.  Removed global variable, and updated with complete keyboard shortcut.

```
;; Preview using qlmanage.
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<SPC>") (lambda () (interactive)
  (start-process "preview" nil "qlmanage" "-p" (dired-get-file-for-visit))))
```

and I have set up a key to delete one process named "preview":

```
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<escape>") (lambda () (interactive)
  (delete-process (get-process "preview"))
```

Comment: Do you know how to keep focus in Emacs, but open a "Quick Look" window on top?  i.e. Emacs keeps keyboard focus.

Comment: @event_jr  Yes, that is exactly what my code does.  With your cursor on a file or folder in dired-mode, evaluate the expression `(start-process "preview" nil "qlmanage" "-p" (dired-get-file-for-visit))`.  I have a special conditional escape key linked to the function written in the answer below:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026083/how-to-use-escape-conditionally-as-a-modifier-key

Comment: (global-set-key (kbd "<escape>") `(menu-item "" ,(lambda () (interactive) (cond ((and (equal buffer-file-name lawlist-todo-file) (and (> (recursion-depth) 0) (not (minibufferp)))) (throw 'exit nil)) ((get-process "preview") (kill-last-process-named "preview")) ((equal (buffer-name) preview-buffer-name) (kill-buffer preview-buffer-name) (delete-window) (exit-recursive-edit)))) :filter ,(lambda (binding) (if (or (and (equal buffer-file-name lawlist-todo-file) (and (> (recursion-depth) 0) (not (minibufferp)))) (get-process "preview") (equal (buffer-name) preview-buffer-name)) binding))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd imagine something like this would work:

```
(defun kill-last-process-named (name)
  (cl-loop with name-re = 
           (format "^%s\\(?:<\\([[:digit:]]+\\)>\\)?" (regexp-quote name))
   for process in (process-list)
   for pname = (process-name process)
   if (string-match name-re pname)
   collect (cons (string-to-number (or (match-string 1 pname) "0")) process)
   into processes
   finally (delete-process (cdar (cl-sort processes '> :key 'car)))))
```