# How to use <escape> (conditionally) as a modifier key

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is it possible to have `<escape>` activate functions when certain conditions exist, yet behave like a modifier key when those conditions are not met?

```
(define-key lawlist-mode-map (kbd "<escape>") (lambda () (interactive)
  (cond
    ((ABC . . .)
      (message "You have satisfied condition ABC."))
    ((DEF . . .)
      (message "You have satisfied condition DEF."))
    (t (The <escape> key shall behave like a modifier key:  ESC- )) )))
```

---

EDIT:  Based upon the *awesome* solution / answer provide by Stefan, the following is an illustration of how to use his code with multiple conditions (e.g., if ABC, then do X; if DEF, then do Y).  I am including this example for slow-learners like myself -- i.e., it took me some time to understand how to apply the code correctly.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<escape>") `(menu-item ""
  ,(lambda () (interactive)
  (cond
    ((Set forth condition ABC.)
      (message "You have satisfied condition ABC."))
    ((Set forth condition DEF.)
      (message "You have satisfied condition DEF."))))
  :filter ,(lambda (binding)
  (if (or (Set forth condition ABC.)
       (Set forth condition DEF.))
    binding))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
(define-key lawlist-mode-map [?\e]
  `(menu-item "" ,(lambda () (interactive) (message "You have satisfied condition ABC."))
              :filter ,(lambda (binding) (if (ABC ...) binding))))
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a sample.  In order to troubleshoot my modification of your code, I switched it over to a global-set-key, but have not been able to generate a message by pressing the escape key:  Any ideas on how to create a working example that demonstrates its usage out of the box?  `(global-set-key [?\e] '(menu-item "" ,(lambda () (interactive) (message "You have satisfied condition ABC.")) :filter ,(lambda (binding) (if (eq major-mode 'text-mode) binding))))`