# Minor Mode Conditional Emacs Shortcuts

Tags: emacs

I have an emacs shortcut set up like so:

```
;; Adding the key mappings to minor mode.
(defvar my-keys-minor-mode-map (make-keymap) "my-keys-minor-mode keymap.")

;; Cancel with one press of escape instead of three.
(define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "<escape>") 'keyboard-quit)

(my-keys-minor-mode 1)

(defconst my-minor-mode-alist (list (cons 'my-keys-minor-mode
                                           my-keys-minor-mode-map)))
(setf emulation-mode-map-alists '(my-minor-mode-alist))
```

This works great to override a shortcut in a truly global way, superseding all other minor modes. However I need a way to have a shortcut behave differently in different minor modes. For example I would like the escape key to run helm-keyboard-quit when helm is running bu run keyboard-quit otherwise. Doing so like:

```
(eval-after-load "helm"
  '(progn
    (define-key helm-map (kbd "<escape>") 'helm-keyboard-quit)))
```

won't work because the global escape shortcut will override it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Here is a link to a related thread entitled **How to use <escape> (conditionally) as a modifier key**:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/20026083/2112489  The method suggested by Stefan in the answer is similar to other implementations in the source code for situations like the `universal-argument`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple lambda.  Something like this (untested):

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "<escape>")
                (lambda()
                  (interactive)
                  (if helm-mode (helm-keyboard-quit)
                    (keyboard-quit))))
```